# Python pymssql how do I insert in a for loop?

Tags: python, pymssql

How do I insert into a table results from another query? My code loops through the query and the results are assigned to variables. As soon as I insert the row the code terminates even though there are still more rows in the result set. What is the proper way to have this code continue and insert all to rows from the result set?

```html
cur.execute (query3)

for row in cur:
    calldate= row['calldate']
    account= row['account']
    call_time= row['Call_Time']
    distributor_name= row['distributor_name']
    callerid= row['callerid']
    call_status= row['call_status']
    partner_revenue= row['partner_revenue']
    tracking_phone= row['tracking_phone']
    quality_string= row['quality_string']
    column9= row['column 9']
    column10= row['column 10']
    column11= row['column 11']
    column12= row['column 12']

    if column9 is None and column10 is None and column11 is None and column12 is None:
        to_db = calldate, account, call_time, distributor_name,callerid, call_status, partner_revenue, tracking_phone, quality_string

    if column9 is not None and column10 is None and column11 is None and column12 is None:
        to_db = calldate, account, call_time, distributor_name,callerid, call_status, partner_revenue, tracking_phone, quality_string +", "+ column9

    if column9 is not None and column10 is not None and column11 is None and column12 is None:
        to_db = calldate, account, call_time, distributor_name,callerid, call_status, partner_revenue, tracking_phone, quality_string +", "+ column9 +", "+ column10

    if column9 is not None and column10 is not None and column11 is not None and column12 is None:
        to_db = calldate, account, call_time, distributor_name,callerid, call_status, partner_revenue, tracking_phone, quality_string +", "+ column9 +", "+ column10 +", "+ column11

    if column9 is not None and column10 is not None and column11 is not None and column12 is not None:
        to_db = calldate, account, call_time, distributor_name,callerid, call_status, partner_revenue, tracking_phone, quality_string +", "+ column9 +", "+ column10 +", "+ column11 +", "+ column12
    
    cur.execute (ins_query,(to_db))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: You're performing an operation (execute) on the object that you're currently iterating over (cur), try to find a way around that

Comment: Thanks Tim. I created a new object cur2 and conn2 and that worked.

Comment: Cool, I posted something similar as answer so this can be "closed"

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in cur:
   #...
   cur.execute (ins_query,(to_db))
```

You're performing an operation (`execute`) on the object that you're currently iterating over (`cur`), find a way around that and your problem should be gone!